# Find a position and return an iterator doesn't work

Tags: c++, iterator

```
template<typename T>
void findposition(T t, long value, typename T::iterator &before, typename T::iterator &position) {
        typename T::iterator it = t.begin();
        while(it != t.end()) {
            before = it;
            position = it;
            if(*it > value) {
                if(before != t.begin()) {
                    before = --it;
                }
                break;
            }
            ++it;
        }
    }

vector<long>::iterator itVectorBefore;
vector<long>::iterator itVectorPosition;
findposition(myVector, 31, itVectorBefore, itVectorPosition);
myVector.insert(itVectorPosition, 31);
```

I don't understand why this piece of code is no working. When i ran it, i will get a segmentation fault. Another strange thing is, when du call findposition(myVector, 1, itVectorBefore, itVectorPosition). Both Iterators will hold a value of 0. I used gdb to investigate, but i couldn't find what is going wrong, because the before has the right value in the function findposition.

When someone of you has an idea what i have made wrong. I would be very pleased for an explanation.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: You're making a copy of the input `vector` and that gets destroyed when the function returns, leaving you with invalid iterators. And a `findposition` function that mutates its input iterator arguments instead of returning an iterator is very strange.

Comment: The function overall is strange. Why require the caller to provide both a `vector` and two uninitialized iterators?

Comment: I find it strange too, but this is an excersie which I need to do.

Comment: @Praetorian thanks a lot. I have totally forgotten, that the object, which is bound to an iterator musst live. Thanks now it is working. I changed T t to T &t.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Neither `before` nor `after` get initialized when the container is empty.

   ```
   typename T::iterator it = t.begin();
   while(it != t.end()) { // When the input is empty, nothing
                          // is set to before or after.
   ```
2. The returned iterators are on a copy of the input argument.

   You should change:

   ```
   template<typename T>
   void findposition(T t, long value,
                     typename T::iterator &before,
                     typename T::iterator &position) {
   ```

to

```
    template<typename T>
    void findposition(T& t, long value,
                      typename T::iterator &before,
                      typename T::iterator &position) {
```